# handling function key press

Tags: c#

I have a C# form with 5 buttons. The users enters the information and depending on the press of a function key, a specific action is performed. <kbd>F9</kbd>-Execute Order, <kbd>F6</kbd>-Save, <kbd>F3</kbd>-LookUp.

I have added the foolowing code:

OnForm_Load

```
this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(KeyEvent);
```

and

```
private void KeyEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) //Keyup Event 
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F9)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Function F9"); 
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Function F6");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Function");

    }
```

but nothing happens

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to set

```
KeyPreview=True
```

for your form. Otherwise key press is swallowed by the control that has focus.

Comment: Also in the last Visual Studio C# standard you need to set method to PreviewKeyDown instead of KeyPress to get function key working.

Comment: Ch3shire, using VS2017 I'm still getting all events on KeyPress with KeyPreview=true. I see no events fired on OnKeyPreviewDown. The setting works fine though.