# Capture function keys F1..F12 in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0, keypress

I cannot capture the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F12</kbd> for my application. I am able to capture regular keys and modifiers such as <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, etc..

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707040/handling-function-key-press) recommends `KeyPreview = True`, however that does not seem to work for my application. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
    AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf KeyDownsHandler
    AddHandler Me.KeyUp, AddressOf KeyUpHandler
End Sub

Private Sub KeyUpHandler(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
        txtMain.AppendText("F1 was pressed!" & Environment.NewLine)
    End If
    txtMain.AppendText( _
        String.Format("'{0}' '{1}' '{2}' '{3}' {4}", e.Modifiers, e.KeyValue, e.KeyData, e.KeyCode, Environment.NewLine))
End Sub

Private Sub KeyDownHandler(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    txtMain.AppendText( _
        String.Format("'{0}' '{1}' '{2}' '{3}' {4}", e.Modifiers, e.KeyValue, e.KeyData, e.KeyCode, Environment.NewLine))
End Sub
```

Comment: User Error :(... I am using a MicrosoftKeyboard and it requires that the key **F Lock** be on.

Comment: That's Awesome.  Haha, happens to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me with the exception that you have a typo in your EventHandler declaration.  Change:

```
AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf KeyDownsHandler
```

to

```
AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf KeyDownHandler
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for verifying my code. I messed up. I am using a Microsoft Keyboard and it requires the key **F Lock** be on.

Answer (score 7):

For capturing keys (including function keys) I've started to use this pattern, which works quite well:

```
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        Select Case keyData
            Case Keys.F2
                ' Do something 

            Case Keys.F3
                ' Do more

            Case Keys.Escape
                ' Crap

            Case Else
                Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)

        End Select

        Return True
    End Function
```

This will automatically suppress every key you handle in the `Select` statement. If you want to use combinations with Shift, Alt or Ctrl you'll just have to `Or` them. Of course this works on a very low `Form` level which makes it independent from any Control you have on that form. It will also trigger weird behavior if you do not know that, like focus-jumps or badly behaving Controls.