# Capturing a key without focusing the window

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook, global-hotkey

I have a application that always checks if a key like <kbd>F12</kbd> is pressed. It doesn't need to have in focus of my main window of my app. I tried this code:

```
public int a = 1;
    // DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
        // Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
        // ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int) Keys.F12);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
        {

            a++;
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I put 0 to this line `RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int) Keys.F12);` so that only if <kbd>F12</kbd> is pressed it will capture.

But it didn't work. How can I solve this?

Here I couldn't understand some lines like:

```
const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID
base.WndProc(ref m);
```

Can anyone help me to understand these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no wrong . But it doesn't work here because the **F12** key is reserved you may try with another key like **F10**, **F11**  etc .

Comment: Note: It might also not work in case you're changing ShowInTaskbar property as the window is destroyed and the registered HotKey with it. Just found out the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

> But it didn't work. How can I solve this?

What do you mean "it didn't work"? The code in your question looks correct to me.

The only reason it might not be working is because the [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) function is returning an error and you're not checking for it. To make this work, you need to add the [`SetLastError` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx) to its declaration, which causes the runtime to cache the Win32 error code that it sets. Once this is done, you can check that error code (if the function returns `false`) by calling the [`GetLastWin32Error` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx). I recommend using the result of this function to generate and throw a [`Win32Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.aspx).

Modify your declaration of `RegisterHotKey` as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd,
                                         int id,
                                         uint fsModifiers,
                                         Keys key);
```

And your call to the function as follows:

```
if (!RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, Keys.F12))
{
   throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Once that's done, I suspect you'll see an exception getting thrown with the error message:

> Hot key is already registered

Well, that makes debugging the problem much simpler, now doesn't it! Chances are you'll need to select a different hot key, since the `RegisterHotKey` function documentation tells us explicitly that:

> The <kbd>F12</kbd> key is reserved for use by the debugger at all times, so it should not be registered as a hot key. Even when you are not debugging an application, <kbd>F12</kbd> is reserved in case a kernel-mode debugger or a just-in-time debugger is resident.

When I run the code and register <kbd>F11</kbd> as a hotkey, it works just fine for me.

---

> Here I couldn't understand some lines like:
>
> ```
> const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
> m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID
> base.WndProc(ref m);
> ```
>
> Can anyone help me to understand these lines?

Sure:

1. The first line declares a constant value that uniquely identifies the hotkey that you installed using the `RegisterHotKey` function. More specifically, it corresponds to the `id` parameter of the function. You passed it in on the initial call.
2. This checks in the window procedure (`WndProc`) to see if the message (`Msg`) that is being processed is the [`WM_HOTKEY` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx). The `WM_HOTKEY` message is posted automatically to your window whenever the hot key you registered with the `RegisterHotKey` function is pressed.

   You shouldn't really be using the magic number `0x0312` directly, though, because you're not the only one who is unsure what it means. Instead, define a constant and use that instead:

   ```
   const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
   m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY
   ```

   The second part of that conditional test (the part after the `&&`) checks the `wParam` field of the message to see if the hot key that was pressed was the one you registered. Remember that `MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID` is the unique ID of your hot key. The `WM_HOTKEY` message documentation tells us that checking the `wParam` is how we determine which hot key was pressed.
3. This calls the base class's window procedure. In other words, what you've done is overridden the virtual `WndProc` method, allowing you to add some *additional* code (your processing of `WM_HOTKEY`). When you're done with your additional logic, you want to continue with the logic of the base class, so you forward the message on.

Comment: Blah, the explanation gets even clearer when I actually run the code for myself. Answer updated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To do a similar thing I implemented a low-level keyboard hook using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That will trap all keyboard messages going through Windows, and allow you to inspect them and if necessary, prevent them going any further.

Take a look at [my KeyboardHandling project](https://github.com/nbarnwell/RocketLauncher/tree/master/KeyboardHandling) in my [RocketLauncher GitHub hobby project](https://github.com/nbarnwell/RocketLauncher). You can take what you need directly from that. I'm going to make it a nuget package soon, too.

Comment: But if i change RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 2, (int) Keys.F12) and  use Ctrl+F10 it works even if it is not focus.

Comment: Fair enough - I made an assumption it was the same as setting them in a designer.

Comment: I would ***strongly*** favor using a global hot key registered through `RegisterHotKey` as opposed to a global keyboard hook. Hooks with a global scope are *extremely* heavy and expensive and should therefore be used only where they are absolutely required. That's not the case here (although I'm not sure about your launcher application, but it may not be there either).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but I feel like this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413172/capture-a-keyboard-keypress-in-the-background/15413314) question... so I'm gonna try to explain it once more:

```
const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
```

is where you save the integer that is used to identify the hotkey. If you need to register more than on hotkey, you will have to declare other integer fields identifying the other hotkeys:

```
const int ANOTHER_ACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 2;
const int AND_ANOTHER_ACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 3;
```

Then,

```
m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID
```

is the condition that enables you to know which hotkey has been typed by the user.

`0x0312` (also declared as `WM_HOTKEY` in the documentation you can found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for instance) is to know if a *registered hotkey* has been pressed:

> When a key is pressed, the system looks for a match against all hot keys. Upon finding a match, the system posts the WM_HOTKEY message to the message queue of the window with which the hot key is associated. If the hot key is not associated with a window, then the WM_HOTKEY message is posted to the thread associated with the hot key.

---

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you cannot use the <kbd>F12</kbd> hotkey:

> The F12 key is reserved for use by the debugger at all times, so it should not be registered as a hot key. Even when you are not debugging an application, F12 is reserved in case a kernel-mode debugger or a just-in-time debugger is resident.

Comment: Awesome explanation, ! don't know why I'm the first one to upvote this, this answer deserves much more than that.