# Listen for keypresses made in a certain process

Tags: c#, winforms

When I have found a certain `Process`, is there any way to listen for all keypresses made when the process window is in focus?

I know that I can register a global key listener. But is there any way to use it only when my process window is "active"/in focus? Or even better; is there a way to capture keys from my process only?

```
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) {

    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("myProcess"))
    {
        Process theProcess = clsProcess;
    }
}
```

Global hotkeys implementation: [Capture a keyboard keypress in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413172/capture-a-keyboard-keypress-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your keyboard hook, check to see if the handle returned by the GetForegroundWindow() API matches that of the MainWindowHandle() property in the Process you are interested in...