# TextBox - F12 function key doesn't fire event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I'm developing app that's running on Raspberry Pi 3 and Windows 10 IoT Core 10.0.16299.125. As part of it I've created class derived form UserControl. It consists of two TextBoxes. Said control needs to handle keyboard inputs on it's own when it has focus. What i need are numeric keys, +, -, *, / and function keys. I got all needed keys to work with OnKeyDown event except for F12.
There will be multiple controls of that type on a Grid for example.

I've tried subscribing to KeyDown/Up for whole class and for input textbox inside it and to override OnKeyDown/Up but the problem is same in all cases, I can't catch F12 key. What's interesting if i catch key events for whole page as long as my control has focus, F12 won't trigger event, otherwise it works.

I've tried also

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.CharacterReceived += CoreWindow_CharacterReceived;

private void CoreWindow_CharacterReceived(CoreWindow sender, CharacterReceivedEventArgs args)
{
 Debug.WriteLine("Key pressed: " + args.KeyCode);
 ...
}
```

But that doesn't get function keys at all.
ProcessCmdKey is not present in UWP. And a lot of other solutions that are targeted rather to WinForms.
It seems to me that the TextBox blocks somehow F12 key but so far I was unable to find answer why or how.

So after some additional searching and testing

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += ...
```

doesn't work either but

```
KeyboardDeliveryInterceptor
```

kind of works. I can catch F12 key when my control has focus but that way key is yank out from normal processing route and TextBox input is blocked. So I'm looking for a way to get the key back on route.

Comment: I reproduced your issue. The same code works on desktop but doesn't work on Windows IoT Core. I'll involve related engineer on this issue.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a chance for immediate solution or is it more a matter of waiting for a new release/build?

Comment: Most of function keys work. If possible you can select one instead of F12?

Comment: Looks like I'll have to.

Comment: you can check following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707040/handling-function-key-press

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. So as said I changed my app so to not use F12 key and i was all fine. And then behold, came Windows IoT Core automatic update and now F4 key stopped working in my UserControl. It would by funny if i not messed up all my work...

Comment: Link is for WinForms not UWP.