# c# detect and send f13-f24 keys

Tags: c#, winforms

I need an application that can detect the keypress of <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd>. I tried making a form and setting keydown and Keypress events and printing in a messagebox the key pressed but when i press <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd>, i don't get a messagebox

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
}

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
}
```

This didn't seem to work.  How can I do this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707040/handling-function-key-press i hope it helps

Comment: @MstfAsan just to confirm u press f13 by holding shift and pressing f1 right, if yes then the solution in that link didn't work for me

Comment: Does your code work for other keys? In other words, have you tested only with F13-F24, or also with other keys (like letters or numbers)?

Comment: What OS are you using? F13-F24 keys aren't recognized in Win10  (or Win 8.1 either, I believe). You can test this by turning on the Windows Narrator functionality, and then press Shift-F1. The narrator just says "Shift F1", not "F13"

Comment: @elgonzo it doesn't work for f13-f24 all other keys work

Comment: @DeanOC i'm running windows 10, is there any way to enable them ? :)

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: @DeanOC i needed empty keys that are not used by many common programs so it doesn't interfere, if f13-f24 is not recognized what can i use? i need total of 6 keys to use, can you help ?

Comment: [Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) and [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Keys.cs,c9ea55b52b93f5c4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture this using  [`System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `KeyEventHandler` will provide a `KeyEventArgs` object that includes a `KeyCode` property. `KeyCode` is a [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx#Syntax) enumeration and supports <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd>.

```
private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F13) {
        //F13
    } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F14) {
        //F14
    } else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F15) {
        //F15
    }
    // etc
}
```

If you don't have a keyboard capable of sending higher F-keys, the <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd> keys are the equivilent of <kbd>SHIFT-F1</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT-F12</kbd>. You can capture this sequence using the `KeyCode` and `Modifiers` (`Modifiers == Keys.Shift`) properties together.

Comment: this does work but not by using the shift keys. i have a trinket and i used it to send the keys and c# registers them flawlessly, thank you

Comment: By "trinket" do you mean the [Adafruit trinket](https://learn.adafruit.com/trinket-usb-keyboard/wiring)? I was just looking at this recently myself. This would be an excellent use for it.

Comment: It's actually a digispark that uses the adafruit trinket keyboard library as it's a lot cheaper. I completed the program that i needed in c# and it worked but when i opened a game it stopped working, any idea how to make the program work all the time?

Comment: Applications only capture input when they're in focus. If you're looking to send input to any application, you need to build a device driver. While that is certainly possible, it is _way_ more complicated.

Comment: i've registered hotkeys so i can use them anywhere in windows but that does not work while playing games for some reason

Comment: Solved it by running it as administrator on startup

Answer (score -2):

Windows 10 doesn't recognize the higher Function keys 13-24. You can test this by turning on the Windows Narrator functionality, and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> -<kbd>F1</kbd>. The narrator just says "Shift F1", not "F13"

So, instead I recommend that you just detect <kbd>Shift</kbd> -<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> -<kbd>F12</kbd> instead.

```
private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{ 
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F1 && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Shift-F1 pressed");
   }
}
```

As MstfAsan commented, you need to use the PreviewKeyDown eventhandler and set the form's KeyPreview property to True for this to work

Comment: after a lot of experimenting i found out that windows 10 does register f13-f24 keys, just not by using the shift method, your approach with using the modifiers will do the work when it comes to a keyboard but i don't need it as it works without it. i got a trinket that presses those keys and c# registers them flawlessly